# NSString Memory Leak Issue, How to autorelease a NSttring?

Tags: iphone, nsstring

I have some NSString inside my program.  If I did a release I think its finished using, it crashed the program.   If I don't release them , it cause memory leakage quite a bit. 
[string1 autorelease] cause executive bad access.

It giving me all kinds of headache.

Comment: You need to show some code in order to get proper help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

release and autorelease is both releasing, just at different points in time. So if one crashes, most likely the other one will as well.

You need to get your memory management right. Maybe use NSZombies, and the static analyzer might be a good helper, too. Also, the debugger might stop right away at the object that causes the problems.

I suggest to read the memory management guide: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html